# SQL to show character encoding of a database/installation in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, query

With only very litte MariaDB experience I need to inspect charater encoding settings on a large scale of MariaDB installations. I want to do this via Ansible and believe it would be easiest to issue some sort of SQL command that returns the encoding setting (corresponding to `default-character-set` setting in `my.cnf`. Ideally from bash.

For postgres i.e. I do `psql -tAc "SHOW server_encoding;"` *and register the result into a variable.

so, actually I am looking for 2 things:

1. an SQL query listing the character encoding default setting for MariaDB
2. a way to send such a query to MariaDB directly from the command line

on the side ... I guess it is possible that different database have different encoding, right?
For my current task it is sufficient to detect the default settings of an installation.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-connection.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql -u ... -p   -e "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'"
```

will show several things.

The connection establishes several things including the charset *for the client*.

The database (`SHOW DATABASE name`) establishes a *default* for new tables; the table `(`SHOW TABLE name`) establishes a _default_ for new columns.  The column's` CHARACTER SET`indicates what is stored (also`SHOW TABLE name`)

Comment: is there any more elegant way to extract just the pure value of such a query (i.e. `utf8mb4`) the doing `mysql -u root -p -e "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_server';" | tail -1 | cut -f2` ?

Comment: `mysql -e 'select @@character_set_server'  | tail +2` or `css=\`mysql -e 'select @@character_set_server'  | tail +2\`` and then use `$css`.  Or (my preference), use Perl or PHP, not shell.

Comment: `> mysql -e 'select @@character_set_server'  | tail -1` does it actually (`tail -1`, not `tail +2` [I guess the '+' was a typo anyway]). tx anyway. As this is a mass operation and I can not say which packages are available on each of the remotes `bash` is my tool of choice. It would be intereseting to know why `perl`, `php` would be better in your eyes though?

Comment: @vrms - perl/php lets me do more complex decisions.  And, if the dataset is big, it is a lot faster (mostly because of connecting only once).

Comment: @vms - On Ubuntu:  `man tail` says  " -n, --lines=[+]NUM ---  output the last NUM lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n +NUM to output starting with line NUM".  (Handy for tossing the header and keeping the rest of the lines.)